# Pegar um valor de estilo inline

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Se considerarmos uma tag HTML com estilo inline dessa forma:

```
<li style="width: 360px; float: left; display: block;">conteudo</div>
```

é possível eu pegar apenas o valor do **width** para fazer um calculo via Javascript ou Jquery?

desde já... obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim amigo, pode usar o clientWidth que ele retornará o valor da largura de seu elemento.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('li').clientWidth, document.querySelector('li').style.display, document.querySelector('li').style.float)
```

```html
<li style="width: 360px; float: left; display: block;">conteudo</li>
```

## EDIT

Para pegar as outras propriedades você pode usar o [DOCUMENT].style.[PROPERTY]

Por exemplo, para pegar a cor da fonte da sua `li` você pode fazer assim:

```
document.querySelector('li').style.color
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Deu certo...
Mas tem uma função dessa para cada estilo? Height, Color...

Comment: @IvanGomes editei a resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: entendi! Muito bom! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize  a funcção css do jquery conforme abaixo:

```js
var width = $("li").css("width"); // retorna: 360px 
width = $("li").width() // retorna 360
console.log(width);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li style="width: 360px; float: left; display: block;">conteudo</div>
```

Documentação: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Nesse caso, para pegar apenas o valor numérico, eu teria que usar um complemento, não é isso?
Tipo parseFloat ou int.

Comment: Coloquei na resposta uma opção equivalente para width:  $("li").width()